# Vercel Problem | 404: NOT_FOUND Code: NOT_FOUND

Tags: reactjs, github, routes, deployment, vercel

https://my-show-rj.vercel.app/
Click on menu options (plays, categories,and tvshow) than the error occurs. Vercel|404:NOT_FOUND

**Vercel.json file**{"rewrites":[{"source":"/(.*)","destination":"/"}]}

**And I also try**{"routes":[{"src":"/(.*)","dest":"/"}]}

**And I try this to**{"routes":[{ "handle":"filesystem"},{"src":"/.*","dest":"/index.html"}]}

[Vercel problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gk9Le.png)